# Can I modify line-break behavior of inline cells?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting

When I insert an `InlineCell` into a `TextCell` that is too long for the whole `InlineCell` to fit on the current line,*Mathematica* pushes the whole `InlineCell` to the beginning of the next line. That is, *Mathematica* seems to prefer dropping the `InlineCell` to the next line over inserting a line break within it. Can I force *Mathematica* to fit as much of an `InlineCell` on a line as possible and put as little as possible on the next line?

I have played around with `LinebreakAdjustments` for the `InlineCell` and the containing cell by setting various values to `0`, but have not been able to produce the behavior I would like.

**Edit:**
If I do not modify `LinebreakAdjustments` for the inline cell or modify any element besides the first (leaving the first element untouched), I get results like this (blue is an `InlineCell`):

[image]

If I set the first element of `LinebreakArguments` (of the `InlineCell`) to `0` I obtain somewhat predictable behavior:

[image]

**Below is the behavior I am trying to produce**. I've just styled the text rather than use an inline cell:

[image]

Comment: It seems an inline cell must be in a rectangle area, so the format you want might not be able to achieve by a single inline cell.